# Xcode/Interface Builder is ignoring the Fill Color setting

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nsbox

I added an NSBox to my view, I set the fill color to the color I want:

[image]

But the color doesn't show up in Interface Builder and doesn't show up when I run the app.  What am I missing?

I've also tried setting it programmatically via

```
[self.myBox setFillColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
```

but the fill color still won't change...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `NSBox` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBox_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBox/setFillColor:):

> **Special Considerations**
>
> Functional only when the receiver’s box type (`boxType`) is `NSBoxCustom` and its border type (`borderType`) is `NSLineBorder`.

Answer (score 2):

set **Box Type** to **Custom** , as in the attachment:

[image]